# Get other child that shares parent with the current view

Tags: android, parent

I'm creating a table in which each row contains text as well as a button. Now when that button is pressed I want to call an event that uses the value of the text next to the button. How can I access the content of that TextView? I can get the `ViewParent` of my button, which should be the row, but there's no method to access that views children.

```
private OnClickListener updateButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v) {
         ViewParent parent = v.getParent();
         //Here I would like to get the first child of that ViewParent
      }
};
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you can get a `ViewParent`, you can then cast it to a `ViewGroup` and get the `View` you need. Your code will look like this:

```
TextView textView = null;
ViewGroup row = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < row.getChildCount(); itemPos++) {
    View view = row.getChildAt(itemPos);
    if (view instanceof TextView) {
         textView = (TextView) view; //Found it!
         break;
    }
}
```

That's it, assuming you have only one `TextView` in your row.

Comment: @Malcolm excellent answer. But if there are more than one textView then how to select a particular textView.

Comment: @MDMalik By using ids or tags. You should use different tags for the text views in the same view group, and when you find a text view, you get its tag and see if this is the view you need.

Answer (score 15):

If you know the ID of a child element then you can do the following:

```
ViewGroup row = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.childID);
```