# android list view on item click listner

Tags: android

my problem is my list onclick listener return LinearLayout not a text view . so i dont know how to catch the clicked item
 thats the simple row xml

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp">

 <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

thats the main

```
  listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {

                        String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                        Log.w("item", item);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
```

this item crash the program because the returned view is  LinearLayout how can i catch the text view inside the LinearLayout ?!

Comment: are you getting the list item from listview??

Comment: use view.findViewById(R.id.TextViewID)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
        {
            TextView c = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

            String sel_item = c.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(RingSubCatActivity.this,sel_item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }});
```

Answer (score 1):

you will receive parent View the you will have to find your text view from parent using

> **view.findViewById**

Then cast and carry on

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,                       long id) {
    if(view !=null)
    {
String item = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_ID)).getText().toString();
Log.w("item", item);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have the problem of several clickable areas in listview's item explained very well:

http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/

Answer (score 0):

Change your onClick to this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
   TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
   String item = textView.getText().toString();
   Log.w("item", item);
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The important thing is that you first need to get the TextView from your parent LinearaLayout.

Answer (score 0):

```
((TextView)((LinearLayout)view).getChildAt(1)).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this

> String val = ((TextView)
>   view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)).getText.toString();

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you need to do, in order:

- make the textview clickable
- make the textview focusable
- attach an OnClick to TextView or OnItemClicked to listview
- make the wrapping LinearLayout `setDecentantFocusability` to `FOCUS_AFTER_CHILDREN`, via XML or code.
- once in the OnClick you will have textview, or if you're going the OnItemClicked route - you will catch the focused item.

So your solution is to either dig in the LinearLayout you receive to get the textview you want, or fix the linearlayout to not take over the focus or the click itself.

Answer (score 0):

If the parent view is LinearLayout, you need to find your textview inside the parent view,
Check the below code, I hope it will work...

```
String item = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using 
`String item = (TextView)((LinearLayout)view).getChildAt(1).getText().toString();`
This is adapted from this answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004013/get-other-child-that-shares-parent-with-the-current-view)

Answer (score 0):

> my list onclick listener return LinearLayout not a text view

That's what its supposed to do.

> i dont know how to catch the clicked item thats the simple row xml

The `onItemClick()` method has the `View` as its second parameter. This is not the `View` that was clicked on, it is the `View` for that Item which adapter provided to `ListView`.

You can search for inner Views by using `findViewById()` on this `View`.

I see that you are trying to get the text String of the item's view. It is always better to get data from adapter than from views:

```
 Object item = listAdapter.getItem(position);
 String text = item.getSomeProperty();
```

Answer (score -1):

In onItemClickListener

```
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)
        Toast.makeText(RingSubCatActivity.this,tv.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }});
```

Use the view object to initialize your textview and get the text to display it in toast.