# How to get a TextView value of a ListViewItem

Tags: java, android, listview

I am using a ListView to build a music playlist such as :

[image]

I want to get the value of the textView in green corresponding to the the item whom button (i.e. the star on the right) was clicked. Any idea please?

activity_row_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rowItem_layout"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.RowItemActivity" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/songName_text"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#8800FF00"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score_text"
                android:layout_width="5dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="#88FF0000"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button_like"
                android:layout_width="7dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

      </LinearLayout>
```

activity_list_view.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.PlayListActivity" >

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/playlist_listView"
       android:layout_width="372dp"
       android:layout_height="394dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_weight="1.42" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

PlayListAdapter.java

```
public class PlayListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Song> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    Song[] data = null;
    SongHolder holder = null;
    ConnectionWrapper connectionWrapper;

    public PlayListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Song[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;        
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;     

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new SongHolder();
            holder.songName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.songName_text);
            holder.score = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.score_text);
            holder.likeButton = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.button_like);
            holder.likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                //get the SongHolder#songName of the item to which belongs the clicked button
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    new Thread(r).start(); 
                }  
            });

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (SongHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Song song = data[position];
        holder.songName.setText(String.valueOf(song.getSongName()));
        holder.score.setText(String.valueOf(song.getScore()));

        return row;
    }

    class SongHolder{
        TextView songName;
        TextView score;
        ImageButton likeButton;

    }
}
```

Comment: I have figured out the solution. Thanks to Malcolm's answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5004133/7558560

Answer (score 0):

No need to use Thread inside ClickListener
Simply use -

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;     

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new SongHolder();
        holder.songName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.songName_text);
        holder.score = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.score_text);
        holder.likeButton = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.button_like);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (SongHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Song song = data[position];
    holder.songName.setText(String.valueOf(song.getSongName()));
    holder.score.setText(String.valueOf(song.getScore()));

    holder.likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                // TextView
                TextView tvSongName = holder.songName;
                // if you want to get song name
                String songName = String.valueOf(song.getSongName());
                Log.v("SongName", "" +songName);
            }  
        });

    return row;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this already and it did not work. The index rendered does not correspond to the item clicked.

Comment: Aah.. okay! You need to `setClickListener` out side` ==null` condition. Edited the code.

Comment: It did not work either :/ is there a way to get the xml tree of the parent item to which belong the button?

Comment: Is your `textview` values setting correctly in row?

Comment: Yeah I have double checked that. The TextView value seems to be allright